# Updating Ember.js data from external event without global controller

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have started learning Ember.js and have been trying to make a page with some data that updates when I get an event (pushed by web sockets).

To make it simple I made an example where I have a list of nodes and when I get a new node I want to call addNode on the controller to add the node. The UI should then update.

The problem I have is that the only way I managed to do this is by having a Global Controller, and then using that in my template instead of my model for the template.

#### I would like to link up the controller to the route, and have a method on the controller add data when the event arrives - not by having some global list or something.

is this possible? And if so how?

I have included my sample so you can change it and show me how its done.

js:

```
x = {title : 'test'};

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("system");
});

App.NodesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addNode: function(nodeInfo){
        this.pushObject(nodeInfo);
    }
});
```

html:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="system">
    {{#each App.NodesController}}
        {{title}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little shady, but I'm not sure if the ember guys have provided another method of getting the controller externally yet.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/imakeg/19/edit)

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvment to what I have. I think. (maybe there is still a better way). One quick thing: why did you need to set the controller to public? It seems to work fine without that

Answer (score 1):

You've to put `needs` in your `system` controller.

```
App.SystemController - Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs:['nodes']
});
```

and in your `system` template,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="system">
    {{#each controllers.nodes}}
        {{title}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

Comment: I see, and then I extend the nodesController instead of create()? But then how do I push an item from an event?